# get filtered array when it changes in directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array in the controller `$scope` which filtered upon clicking on one of two buttons to filter it.

I noticed that the directive controller enters only when then filtered array becomes larger.
I tried to check it with `console.log`, it renders the filtered array to the DOM but doesn't prints the filtered array in the `console.log`.

I would like to `console.log` the filtered array any time it change its values.

here is my code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['components']).controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [{name: 'a', age: 30}, {name: 'b', age: 25}, {name: 'c', age: 15}];

    $scope.farr = $scope.arr.filter(item => item.age > 20);

        $scope.func = function(value) {
        $scope.farr = $scope.arr.filter(item => item.age > value);
    }

}]);

angular.module('components', []).directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            arr: '=',
            p: '='
        },
        template: '<div>Hello {{p.name}}</div>',
        controller: (function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.arr); // prints once $scope.arr becomes larger           
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <button ng-click="func(25)">above 25</button>
    <button ng-click="func(20)">above 20</button>
    <div class="container">
        <hello-world arr="farr" p="obj" ng-repeat="obj in farr"></hello-world>   
    </div>
<div>
```

Hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watch to the link function of the directive and `console.log` the array, every time when the array changes:

```
 link : function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$watch(function(){return scope.arr;}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue != oldValue)
                console.log(scope.arr);
      });
 }
```